# Weird behaviour of Management Studio

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

My sql managment studio is behaving weird with thi sql script.

Bug in the Sql File .

[SqlScript.](http://cid-c2df3b22c4365b9b.office.live.com/self.aspx/Online%5E_Shared%5E_Apps/SqlBug/SQLQuery3.sql)

Steps to reproduce:

Here is the sql file. Open it in Sql Management studio 2008. Comment the line between the identity insert on and off. cut it and paste it in new query window. Try to do more than once... it shows some weird behaviours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I posted in the comments to your closed question the problem is that the string in the SQL Script when looked at in a Hex Viewer is

```
0001000000000000006800FA004D00B2
0019002D00CF006800400078011920B3
00780192010E00FE00E4001D00C3004D
006400AD0069007100
```

The `0000` character is the `NULL` character. This marks the end of a string in `C` and explains the odd behaviour you are seeing. You should probably change the datatype of the password field to `binary`/`varbinary`.